# How to enable logging/tracing with Axum?

Tags: rust, rust-axum, rust-tracing

I'm learning Axum and I will like to add logging to the service I have put together but unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

I have added tower-http to use the `TraceLayer` and added it to my app:

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
axum = "0.6.1"
tower-http = { version = "0.3.5", features = ["trace"] }
```

```
use tower_http::trace::TraceLayer;

let app = Router::new()
    .route("/:name/path", axum::routing::get(handler))
    .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http())
```

But when I start the application and make requests to the endpoint, nothing gets logged. Is there any configuration step I could have missed?

Comment: @kmdreko I wasn't before, but now I added it, and yet there is still no log output

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set up a "subscriber" to output the tracing events created by the `TraceLayer`. You can get up and running quickly with the [tracing-subscriber](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-subscriber) crate :

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tracing = "0.1.37"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.16"
```

```
tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_max_level(tracing::Level::DEBUG)
    .init();
```

By default, `TraceLayer` will log with a `DEBUG` level so the `.with_max_level` is important for viewing those logs. You can change the behavior of `TraceLayer` by using the customizable `on_*` methods.

See also:

- [How to use the tracing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70013172/2189130) for more introductory tracing configurations
- [How to log and filter requests with Axum/Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74302133/2189130) to help reduce the noise

Comment: What if you want the user to be able to configure the level of the logs? How can that be done? The examples above looks like it decides what the log level will be directly in the code and that may not be desirable

Comment: @FinlayWeber Sounds like you may be interested in [`EnvFilter`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.16/tracing_subscriber/struct.EnvFilter.html)/[`.with_env_filter()`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.16/tracing_subscriber/fmt/struct.SubscriberBuilder.html#method.with_env_filter) so the logging level can be customized by an environment variable. And its more customizable than just globally.